# Google OAuth verification without monolithic GoogleApiClient source tree (php)

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-oauth

After doing client-side google signin (using javascript), the client sends the login to the server, which should do a quick validation sanity-check that it isn't spoofed.

The official recommendation is to use the Google API Client Libraries by adding this to the php composer file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

`php composer.phar --no-dev` results in **+5,800** files even with **--no-dev !**

I really was hoping for a lighter solution for just a quick login validation.

I've looked at the code and the core of what OAuth validation is doing is public key decrypting (RS256) a blob that's returned. (This is in the Firebase JWT api) This is probably <500 lines of commented php code. There is some complexity around downloading Google's public key and caching it, but surely not 6,000 files worth.

- guzzlehttp/ is 101 files
- google/apiclient/ is 33 files
- google/apiclient-services/ is **5344 files**
- monolog/ is 195 files
- phpseclib/ is 43 file
- psr/ 40 file

There are *a lot* of features that just aren't required. apiclient-services includes Adsense, Blogger, Google Books, Manufacturer Center and on and on.

I can tear out just the code I need, but that seems like a support issue long-term.

I was wondering if anyone's found a better solution? 
Is it possible with finer-grained top-level composer.json to exclude source files that aren't required (like all of apiclient-services)?

Comment: I have the exact same question. I was wondering if you ever found an answer? Unfortunate that no one has answered!

Comment: Yes. I extracted out just the PHP sections of code I needed to do the work.

It solved the problem, but introduces a long-term maintenance issue since security patches from the original source needs to be re-ported.

I will try to make time and put together a github gist and post it here.

Comment: I ended up using this smaller library instead: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google